# How to get to folder view in github wiki

Tags: github, github-pages, wiki

I'm reading this article: [applying-git-to-github-wikis](https://labs.inn.org/2014/05/19/applying-git-to-github-wikis/)

In the article there's this screenshot that seems to show the files and folders of the wiki on github.com:

[image: picture of folders and markdown files]

But when you go to the wiki tab in github, it renders the wiki. And the wiki is a seperate respository from the github respository that it is a wiki for. So I'm wondering, how do you go about navigating to that UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 2014 article which might not be inline with the current wiki management at GitHub.

A wiki like [the one for moby (docker)](https://github.com/moby/moby/wiki) can be cloned with https://github.com/moby/moby.wiki.git, but has no direct web representation like a regular repository.